# Getting an error namely android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: EBUSY (Device or resource busy)

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I just get this error in other phone. I have installed the app in my phone and it works fine. But when i install the same app in other phone (through android studio) i get this error and the app stops. I am asking for the Internet permission through `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Also, I process my data through JSON. I am developing this app to get weather details through api from `api.openweather.org`. It does work perfectly in my phone(running on android version 8.1) but not in any other phone(running on android version 10.0). Also i have set minimum sdk as android 8.0.

It also shows this error:

> Exception in CronetUrlRequest: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED, ErrorCode=2, InternalErrorCode=-106, Retryable=false